# ASP.net - Returning an invalid json on client when serializing a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

This question is different from the one suggested by the mod. because I am returning a string and not an object here.

I am attempting to send a json string back to the client. However it is invalid (the formatting is incorrect) any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

This is the server side

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string foo()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        response["itemID"] = "ABC";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    }
```

and on the client side I am doing this

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
       string clientResponse = client.DownloadString(url);
       Dictionary<string, string> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(clientResponse);

    }
```

clientRepsonse is apparently not properly formatted json its like this (shown below). Thats why it cannot be de-searialized

```
"{\"itemID\":\"ABC\"}"
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this.
In the locals in visual studio it looks like this  `"\"{\\\"itemID\\\":\\\"ABC\\\"}\""`

And in preview it looks like this
`"{\"itemID\":\"ABC\"}"`

Comment: Are the escape characters included in the json string, or is that just how it's being displayed by visual studio? `"{\"itemID\":\"ABC\"}"` as a string deserializes to a `Dictionary<string,string>` just fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: Let me post what visual studio shows

Comment: What error are you getting? Or you just looked at the escaped string? I have tried this `var dc=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>("{\"One\":\"A\",\"Two\":\"B\",\"Three\":\"C\"}");` and it works fine.

Comment: I am going to post the exact result that i see, I am running it now

Comment: @JonathonChase this is how its showing up `"{\"itemID\":\"ABC\"}"` in visual studio. When I attempt to deserailize it to a dictionary it fails. I am not sure why its failing. The string looks fine to me. But in the locals it looks like this `"\"{\\\"itemID\\\":\\\"ABC\\\"}\""
`

Comment: You should return an `ActionResult` like suggested in the duplicate. Then you'll be able to deserialise into the Dictionary. The string produced by the controller is not valid representation of json

Comment: Okay, you are returning JSON string which is getting escaped again. Read the referred question and return JSON instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [Produces("application/json")] to your controller level.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```